# store image into postgresql bytea field using yiiframework

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I am trying to store image into postgresql bytea field.

```
$data=file_get_contents("filename.jpg");
pg_escape_bytea($data);
```

Then I am inserting this into database. After that when I select the image from the database it is showing Resource_id #. If I use `pg_unescape_bytea()` on the selected field then it is showing null value.

How can I store and retreive data from postgresql using yii?

Comment: It would be better to store the image as an image on your file system and store the path to it instead. If you need to do it that way, sorry for misleading you.

Answer (score 1):

> [Yii DAO is built on top of PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao)

With PDO you shouldn't use the `pg_*` functions, as these belongs to a different extension.

If you really want to store the image in `bytea`, you should use the [prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)/[bind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) mechanism (or its [Yii-DAO equivalent](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#binding-parameters)) to store image contents, and you should be aware that in (postgres) PDO the type `bytea` is returned as a [stream](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php), so you can read it with functions like [`fread()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) or [`stream_get_contents()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php).

Answer (score 0):

The way I do:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

$upload = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'upload');
$data = pg_escape_bytea(file_get_contents($upload->tempName));
$model->myfield = new Expression("'{$data}'");
```

To retrieve:

```
$data = stream_get_contents($model->myfield);
```